# Access Model Methods with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is how I've been accessing model methods from my controllers:

```
$contactsTable = new Application_Model_DbTable_ContactsBasics();
$contact = $basicsTable->getContact($contacts_id);
```

How can I do the same by doing it like this?

```
$contact = Application_Model_DbTable_ContactsBasics::getContact($contacts_id);
```

I find the second way a little faster and easier to read, what do I have to do make it work, I already tried it but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you have to declare the `getContact()` method as `static`. Anyway you should declare a static method only when it has sense, not just because of a "more readable" code.

Comment: Thank you for poiting in me in the right direction, I read up on [static methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) and I came across this: _Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static._ I won't be using static methods because I use the $this variable a lot in my models.

Comment: You can check if you can replace $this by 'self'